# Can't use anything(like touch, network and ADB) after freezing android 7

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, custom-rom

I have an app which is running videos 24 hr using exo-player. sometimes app running fine all day but sometimes whole android box were freeze and we don't do anything except power reboot. and also we don't have any logs to trace this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect your app's memory usage with Memory Profiler.

Link: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Comment: I have already monitored through a profiler it only consumes a maximum of 0.2 GB out of 2 GB.